# Julia, read data from text file (Fortran- like)

Tags: file, julia, readline

How to convert following simple Fortran to Julia?

```
integer n,i,ne,m,k(10,2)
real x(10),a(10)
open(1,'t.txt')
READ(1,*) n,ne
do  i=1,n
    READ(1,*) m,x(m)
end do
do  i=1,ne
      READ(1,*) m,a(m),(k(m,j),j=1,2)
end do
end
```

The contents of file t.txt could be

```
4 3
2  4.1
3  2.2
4  7.1
1  1.1
2  3.3  1  4
3  4.4  2  4
1  7.7  1  2
```

I'm old Fortraner. I made several attempts using readline without any luck..

Comment: For all that are not fluent in both languages, what's the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

A revised version of [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77638547/).

```
open("t.txt", "r") do io
    firstrow = split(readline(io))
    n, ne = parse.(Int, firstrow)

    x = fill(NaN, n)  # or memory alloc w/o filling `x = Vector{Float64}(undef, n)`
    for i in 1:n
        row = split(readline(io))
        m, x[m] = parse.((Int, Float64), row)
    end

    a = fill(NaN, ne)
    k = fill(0, (ne, 2))
    for i in 1:ne
        row = split(readline(io))
        m, a[m] = parse.((Int, Float64), row[1:2])  # or `@view row[1:2]`
        k[m, :] = parse.(Int, row[3:4])
    end

    @show x  # x = [1.1, 4.1, 2.2, 7.1]
    @show a  # a = [7.7, 3.3, 4.4]
    @show k  # k = [1 2; 1 4; 2 4]
end
```

Comment: Nice implementation of Julia style. But, I still think the above Fortran code is much clearer and even shorter. It uses only one simple read function. Compare it to Julia alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution by using combination of 'split' and 'parse' functions to read the group of input data and assign them to variables. Reading such type of data though isn't as easy, direct and clear as in Fortran..

```
open("t.txt","r") do bb 
x=[]
k=[]
a=[]
strs=[]
strs = split(readline(bb))
n=parse(Int64, strs[1])
ne=parse(Int64, strs[2])   
for i in 1:n
  strs = split(readline(bb))
  m=parse(Int64, strs[1])
  x[m]=parse(Float64, strs[2])
end
for i in 1:ne
  strs = split(readline(bb))
  m=parse(Int64, strs[1])
  a[m]=parse(Float64, strs[2])
  k[m,1]=parse(Int64, strs[3])
  k[m,2]=parse(Int64, strs[4])
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Fortran, and it's not clear what the results are supposed to be. But a rough guess at a not very idiomatic Julia equivalent is:

```
k = zeros(10, 2)
x = zeros(Float64, 10)
a = zeros(Float64, 10)

open("/tmp/t.txt") do f
    n, ne = map(n -> parse(Int, n), split(readline(f)))
    for i in 1:n
        m, _v = split(readline(f))
        x[parse(Int, m)] = parse(Float64, _v)
    end
    for i in 1:ne
        m, _v1, j, _v2 = split(readline(f))
        # eg (m, _v1, j, _v2) = ("2", "3.3", "1", "4")
        a[parse(Int, m)] = parse(Float64, _v1)
        k[parse(Int, m), parse(Int, j)] = parse(Float64, _v2)
    end
end
```

```
julia> k
10×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.0  0.0
 4.0  0.0
 0.0  4.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> x
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.1
 4.1
 2.2
 7.1
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> a
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 7.7
 3.3
 4.4
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

Comment: The `k` reading is incorrect, here. Each read should set a complete row of `k`